# Dropdown Menu Moves Contents "position:absolute"

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a dropdown menu in html. However when I position:absolute, my drop menu doesn't show. When I get rid of position:absolute; the dropdown menu shifts contents. I think it's something small. I'm not sure what I did wrong.

```css
    .navbar{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: middle;
        top:0;
        width: 100%;
        position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,255,0), 
            rgba(255,0,0,1));
        position: relative;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position:absolute;
        background-color:grey;
        min-width: 200px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class = "navbar">
        <li><a href = "#about"> About</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#resume">Résumé </a></li>
        <li>
            <div class = "dropdown">
             <button class = "dropbtn">Portfolio </button>
             <div class = "dropdown-content">
                 <a href = "#CS"> Computer Science </a>
                 <a href = "#E"> Entrepreneurship </a>
                 <a href = "#P"> Photography </a>
             </div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href = "#contact"> Contact </a></li> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I had "Approved" an edit hastily that should be reverted to disapproval since the editor included bootstrap which is never insinuated.

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar is not showing the overflowing content, simply adding `overflow: visible` can fix this issue.

```css
    .navbar{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #333;
        position: middle;
        top:0;
        width: 100%;
        position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,255,0), 
            rgba(255,0,0,1));
        position: relative;
        overflow: visible;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position:absolute;
        background-color:grey;
        min-width: 200px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class = "navbar">
        <li><a href = "#about"> About</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#resume">Résumé </a></li>
        <li>
            <div class = "dropdown">
             <button class = "dropbtn">Portfolio </button>
             <div class = "dropdown-content">
                 <a href = "#CS"> Computer Science </a>
                 <a href = "#E"> Entrepreneurship </a>
                 <a href = "#P"> Photography </a>
             </div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href = "#contact"> Contact </a></li> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but now my "background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,255,0), rgba(255,0,0,1));" doesn't show

Comment: can you share the jsfiddle of that code? so i can look into the issue?